# Error '0x80045039' when using GetVoices method

Tags: vb.net, text-to-speech, sapi

I am getting an error "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x80045039'", when I use GetVoices method

my code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim SAPI

    SAPI = CreateObject("SAPI.SPVoice")


    SAPI.voice = SAPI.GetVoices.Item(0)
    SAPI.Speak("hello world)

End Sub
```

when removing the following line the code works fine:

```
API.voice = SAPI.GetVoices.Item(0)
```

I tried to run visual studio as administrator but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: You might check out this article on CodeProject, it might give you what you need.  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19334/Text-to-Speech-using-Windows-SAPI